# Css rotate a div 180 degrees in place

Tags: html, css, transform

I have a rectangular div that I want to rotate by 180 degrees in certain scenarios.

I am using the css transform property to rotate the div.

This works nicely on chrome but on edge what happens is that the div goes outside of its container div. I want the div to be in its original position itself but rotated by 180 degrees.

```css
.container {
  display: flex, flex-direction: row, align-items: center, justify-content: flex-end, writing-mode: vertical-lr width:100px, height:100px, border: solid red 1px;
}

.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg); 
    transform-origin: left top
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rotate">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you have now. Use a snippet.

Comment: You are using commas instead of semicolons in your CSS. Also, the `rotate` div is probably not the size you expect (you can see it better by adding a background). You could try adding `display: inline-block;` to `.rotate` to make it the size of its content, and removing the `transform-origin` (to use its default value of `center`)

Answer (score 16):

```css
.container {
  display: flex, flex-direction: row, align-items: center, justify-content: flex-end, writing-mode: vertical-lr width:100px, height:100px, border: solid red 1px;
}

.rotate {
  font-size: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
          transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="rotate">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use `transform: rotateX(180deg);` so that the element will stay in place while rotating

Comment: That flips the element vertically. Unlikely what the question is asking for, as when not specified, "rotation" often refers to a standard 2d rotation (around the Z axis if you consider the plane in 3 dimensions)

Comment: Can you please show an example what exactly you want?

Answer (score 2):

As @Bali Balo points out, none of the `.container` CSS will work because of the commas.

I suspect (though it's hard to know for sure without a working example) that your issue is two competing layout systems. Your Flex CSS is telling the content to justify to the end – or right side (`justify-content: flex-end`). Your transform CSS is telling `.rotate` to pivot around the top left corner.

[image: Rotation demonstration]

Chrome is honoring your `align-items: center` on the container when it rotates child elements. I haven't got an Edge test browser, but I suspect it is honoring the 'transform-orgin' you have on the inner DIV.

So `transform-origin: center center;` should make the rectangle pivot around its center rather than its top left corner.

All up, I think I'd try to clear up some of that Flex code if it's not helping.